# iOS Simulator cuts off right half of the view controller screen

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I am trying to build my first app using Xcode stroyboard. The first view is just a label in the centre of screen of the view controller. But in iOS Simulator only the left half of the screen was shown: the label was shown at the right edge of the simulator screen, looked like simulator cut off the right half of the screen.

Anyone knows how to make the simulator to show the whole screen with the same format as in view controller?

Comment: Add links to your images elsewhere and someone can edit them in.

Comment: I have rolled back to a previous version, because the question should consist of... just the question. I would recommend adding a comment to the existing answer if you want to add something. By keeping the question an actual question makes it easier for other people to find this question and use the answer, without even needing to ask a new question. As for why new users are not allowed to post images, see [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268471/2209007).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This definitely looks like an autolayout problem.

1. Hold ctrl.
2. Click and drag from label to corner of view controller.
3. Click **center horizontally in container**.
4. Repeat steps 1-2.
5. Click **center vertically in container**.

Take a look into this [source](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/) to learn more about autolayout. (It even shows the problem you're having from the start.)

Comment: It was due to the Xcode version. The solution from ThatGuy was helpful. THANKS.  To   make sure UI elements are not chopped off from the right side in screen, add Training Space to container margin.